# Вывод построчно. print_r(get_included_files());

Tags: php

Вставляю `print_r(get_included_files());` в файл `.php` и при обращении через браузер он выдаёт мне список подключённых к нему других файлов.
Как сделать, чтобы они выводились построчно?
Пробовал:

```
$filess = print_r(get_included_files());
echo $filess.'<br>';
```

Но это не помогло

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например вот так:

```
array_map(function($file) {
    echo $file . '<br>';
}, get_included_files());
```

Или церез цикл

```
$files = get_included_files();

foreach ($files as $file) {
    echo $file . '<br>';
}
```